# Trying to set up an auto_increment input system

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax-error, auto-increment, increment

I'm new to this website so let me know if I'm doing something wrong.

I'm trying to make a system where every time a value is inserted into the table, it's given an ID. So the first one would be 21, next one 22, 23, and so on.

I'm fairly new at SQL so I threw this together hoping it'd work, and I figured I'd come here and ask for some help.

This is what I thought up:

```
CREATE TABLE _increment
(
    ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_id varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    group_id varchar(255),
    alias varchar(255),
    notes varchar(255),
    value varchar(255),
    hash varchar(255),
    function_id varchar(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)    
)

INSERT INTO _increment
(`user_id`, `group_id`, `alias`, `hash`, `function_id`, `value`, `disabled`)
VALUES ('262', NULL, NULL, 'john', 'wewbsite.ca/', NULL, '0');
```

Comment: Welcome at SO. Please add the error message you get to your question. Read this message carefully and ask what you don't understand. We don't know what you've already done to remedy your error.

Comment: If you count the columns in your INSERT statement, the list of names within the first pair of parentheses, you get 8. If you count the values in the VALUES part, you get 7. There's one value missing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I can't test it out live right now, instead I'm forced to use Syntax Checkers online. It says I don't have the right syntax near my INSERT_INTO area. I haven't really done much to remedy this error because I don't know much, and to be honest I can't locate the error.

Comment: You should be getting: **Unknown column 'disabled' in 'field list'**. If you don't, you've messed something with your testing.

Comment: I've removed the eighth value, but I'm still getting a **"wrong syntax near INSERT INTO"** error.

Comment: You should close your `CREATE TABLE` statement with a semicolon, just as you did with your `INSERT INTO` statement.

Comment: Oh, haven't thought of that. So close it right after _increment or on the ")" at the end of the statement?

Comment: At the end of the statement. Else you'll get a new error message and I'm sure you won't have a new one.

Comment: Alright. I typed out the error I get when I check it online at www.piliapp.com/mysql-syntax-check/?ref=php-syntax-check.
It is "Check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO _increment (`user_id, `group_id, `alias`, `hash`, `function_id`' at line 14, "

Comment: I just don't know where you are now. But if I change the column name `disabled` that not exists in your table definition to `notes` that exists, then it works, see a [working demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1e8b61/1)

Comment: Thank you very much, that seems to do the trick. I have some other questions but they aren't directly related to this, after I post it could you take a look at it?

Comment: If you've got another question ask a new one. Be sure to [ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). There are many users reading those questions. Better questions mean better answers. Please close this question by accepting the answer that helped you most (even if we did most by our comments).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CREATE TABLE _increment
The main points were some syntax errors, namely a missing semicolon at the end of the `CREATE TABLE` statement

```
CREATE TABLE _increment
(
    ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_id varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    group_id varchar(255),
    alias varchar(255),
    notes varchar(255),
    value varchar(255),
    hash varchar(255),
    function_id varchar(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)    
);                                 -- this one was missing
```

and a wrong column name in the `INSERT INTO` statement

```
INSERT INTO _increment
(`user_id`, `group_id`, `alias`, `hash`, `function_id`, `value`, `notes`)   -- not `disabled` 
VALUES ('262', NULL, NULL, 'john', 'wewbsite.ca/', NULL, '0');
```

If one hasn't got a mysql server ready to experiment and learn then I can recommend [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) to test such statements.

Answer (score 0):

I would use GO command after creating table (in SQL Server - I think there exists similar command in MySQL).

I see that in table definition you have NOTES column, but in INSERT INTO statement you have DISABLED column instead.